# Cannot Create Arrays of Parameterized Types

Tags: java, arrays

I was reading java docs

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays
```

It says

```
"You cannot create arrays of parameterized types"
```

So I'm able to create below array of ArrayList using below code

```
ArrayList<Integer>[] al = new ArrayList[n];
```

But why its showing error on below code. Its also an array of `List`s. Why its showing compile time error ?

```
List<Integer>[] arrayOfLists = new List<Integer>[2];
```

WHat's parameterized type here actually .? I think its `Integer`, but its present in both types of arrays.

Comment: Your first example is a **raw type**; and thus bypasses Java generic type checking entirely.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, What's not a raw type in second example ..?

Comment: `List<Integer>` is a parameterized interface which still counts as a parameterized type.

Comment: The generic type declaration on the right hand side (the bit in diamond brackets - `List<Integer>` in your example). Java uses type erasure at runtime for generics, so at runtime it doesn't know that arrayOfLists  is meant to only contain Lists of `List<Integer>` type.

Comment: @stringy05, On right hand side if I do like this new List[2]; it allows but what about left hand side, generic type is still mentioned there ...? Dont you think its syntactically wrong ?

Comment: It's the difference between a compile time error and a run time error; see also [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/2970947)